# How to setup travis-ci with Laravel 5? InvalidArgumentException

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, travis-ci

I tried to run Travis-ci with Laravel 5.2 several times, but nothing works for me. I can run phpunit locally and it works, but not in travis.

My current travis.yml:

```
language: php

php:
  - 5.5
  - 5.6
  - 7.0
  #- hhvm
  #- nightly

sudo: required

before_script:
  - mkdir bootstrap/cache
  - mkdir storage
  - mkdir storage/framework
  - mkdir storage/framework/cache
  - sudo chmod -R 777 bootstrap/cache
  - sudo chmod -R 777 storage
  #- cp .env.travis .env
  - composer self-update
  - composer install --no-interaction
  #- php artisan key:generate

script:
  - vendor/bin/phpunit
```

The latest error in travis is
a failed request to [http://localhost]. Received status code [500].
Caused by exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Please provide a valid cache path.' in /home/travis/build/Saibamen/laravel5-travis/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php:15392

All commits and travis logs are here: [click](https://github.com/Saibamen/laravel5-travis/commits/master)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct travis file is:

```
language: php

php:
  - 5.6
  - 7.0

before_script:
  - mkdir bootstrap/cache
  - mkdir storage
  - mkdir storage/app
  - mkdir storage/framework
  - mkdir storage/framework/sessions
  - mkdir storage/framework/cache
  - mkdir storage/framework/views
  - chmod 777 -R storage
  - cp .env.travis .env
  - mysql -e 'create database homestead_test;'
  - composer self-update
  - composer install --no-interaction
  - php artisan key:generate

script:
  - vendor/bin/phpunit
```

Answer (score 1):

My .travis.yml

```
language: php

php:
  - 5.6
  - 7.0

before_script:
  - cp .env.travis .env
  - composer self-update
  - composer install --no-interaction
  - php artisan key:generate

script:
  - vendor/bin/phpunit
```

Comment: https://travis-ci.org/Saibamen/laravel5-travis/jobs/152690298 failed to open /home/travis/build/Saibamen/laravel5-travis/bootstrap/cache/services.php

Comment: I believe i used [this](https://gist.github.com/gilbitron/5cac0ac5fa07e9b354ac) one and modified a little but this one should work.

Comment: I always have this error: https://travis-ci.org/Saibamen/laravel5-travis/jobs/160826375

Comment: Ok it works with this config :) https://travis-ci.org/Saibamen/laravel5-travis/jobs/160830063